# Openpyxl adding page number to footer for printing

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working on using Python and Openpyxl to automate pulling data from a PoS CSV dump into an Excel workbook formatted the way we need it for a monthly stockcount, and have successfully got everything working apart from adding page numbers to the footer of each printed sheet. If I could get this into the format "Page x of y" that would be perfect.

I've found this (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/page.html#PrintPageSetup) which I think has the answer somewhere, but I'm very new to Python, so to be honest it's all a bit beyond me, so I'd appreciate some help from someone more knowledgable!

TIA.

**Edit**

I found the solution - as follows:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.oddFooter.center.text = "Page &P of &N"
ws.evenFooter.center.text = "Page &P of &N"
```

Comment: Please include your code so far and be more specific.